# sql query issue step by step

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are 3 relations:

- `person(id, first_name, original_surname, new_surname, birth_date)`
- `marriage(m_id, w_id, date)`
- `child_of(child_id, father_id, mother_id)`

and the query for half siblings is:

```
(
  select P1.id, P2.id
  from (
    person join child_of on id=child_id
  ) as P1
    natural join (person join child_of on id=child_id) as P2
         using (father_id)
  where P1.mother_id < P2.mother_id
)
union
(
   select P1.id, P2.id
   from (
     person join child_of on id=child_id
   ) as P1
     natural join (person join child_of on id=child_id) as P2
             using (mother_id)
   where P1.father_id < P2.father_id
 )
```

I am new to sql and I am trying to understand what happens "behind the scenes". Which table is created in the end and how the query finds half siblings.

Is P1 is created and then it joins with P2 and then they both join together and how does the `where` affect on the table?

What is the chronological order of things here, what happens first, second...

Comment: Your code does not create any tables. Are you asking how the result set is being built?

Comment: In this case `where` serves as a *join condition*.

Comment: What's will all those brackets???

Comment: @PM77-1 yes. I mean the tables that are there "behind the scenes"

Answer (score 1):

Processing here won't go beyond the parser step, which will detect a syntax error in the query. Natural joins (which are best avoided) don't sport a `USING` clause.

But assuming that you mean `INNER` instead of `NATURAL`, the answer depends a lot on the amount and distribution of the data in the tables, as well as the configuration of the database.

Also, indexes on the tables have an influence on the answer.

There are many different ways to execute such a query, and the database engine will automatically select the one it thinks is fastest under the given circumstances.

You can use the `EXPLAIN` command to see which execution plan PostgreSQL chooses.

Comment: Short but very good answer.
Or better:  short AND very good answer.  :-)